# Browse the values of multiple fields and insert them into the same column

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, oracle-apex, procedure

I am trying to create a functionality for my oracle apex application using duplicated row. Let's say that i have a **vehicle table.**

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles
(
    brand VARCHAR2(50),
    model VARCHAR2(50),
    comment VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

I first created a PL/SQL procedure that is currently working, which duplicate the row n amount of times, selected by the user. For example, if the user has 5 of the same vehicles, he can enter "5", and the application will insert 5 times the same vehicle, with different primary keys of course.

What I am trying to achieve, is to give the possiblity for the user to add a custom comment on every row. For example, he would have 5 of the same cars, with different comment on each one.

Here's the code of my procedure when the user is inserting the cars :

```
FOR i IN 1..:P27_NUMBER_VEHICLES -- this represents the numbers of cars the users want to insert
LOOP
INSERT INTO vehicles(brand, model) 
VALUES(:P27_BRAND, :P27_MODEL);
END LOOP;
END;
```

This creates 5 of the same vehicles, but i want the user to be able to add 5 different comments on each vehicle, here's [an example of my insertion form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhgTj.png), the comment field appears dynamically based on the numbers that the user want to insert
[image]

I've now tried to update my procedure with the comment, i tried to give a name that could be dynamically changed by the procedure, I named it :P27_COMMENT_0 / 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5. So i tried to add :P27_COMMENT_ || i (the index of the loop) to try to browse the differents fields automatically, here's the code :

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..:P27_NUMBER_VEHICLES 
LOOP
INSERT INTO vehicles(brand, model, comment) 
VALUES(:P27_BRAND, :P27_MODEL, :P27_COMM_ || i);
END LOOP;
END;
```

This unfortunately doesn't work.

I hope you guys could have a solution for me. To summarize everything, I am trying to duplicate a row witha  loop, but still being able to add a custom entry for each one on a specific column.

Do not hesitate to ask for more details, as I may have forgot some important things.

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

***UPDATE***

Here's how it is showing, I can't write anything on it :

[image]

Comment: How do you dynamically generate P27_COMM items, do you use APEX_ITEM?

Comment: I've mad it a bit less complex, there's a limit of 10 items max by insert, so there are 10 comments fields. These fields are hidden unless they meet the required condition which is :P27_NUMBER_VEHICLE >= 1/2/3/4/..../10. so if the users select 4 items to insert, there will be the 4 first comment fields appearing on the page.

Comment: Then you can't loop through your items. Submit every item, check if it is not null and , if the condition is met, do the insert. BTW check your model not sure if you want all those duplicates.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you for the answer, would you have an other solution if my items were dynamically generated with APEX_ITEM ?

Comment: Yes, I do......

Comment: Dou you have a tutorial or something else that could help me to do so ?

Comment: I will write an answer, just a moment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion is easier to use APEX_ITEM, as follow:

1. Add an Interactive Report region or sub region after your items.
2. Set the IR SQL query as:

```sql
SELECT 
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
     p_idx => 1,  
     p_attributes=> 'placeholder="Comment '|| LEVEL ||'"') AS Name
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_NUMBER (:P16_NUM)
;
```

`:P16_NUM` is an item which holds the number of items to display. Do not forget to add it in **Page Items to Submit** in the Source section of the IR.

3. Add a submit button.
4. In **Processing** create a new process an iterate through the items as:

```sql
BEGIN
  apex_debug.enable;
  for i in apex_application.g_f01.FIRST..apex_application.g_f01.LAST loop
    apex_debug.info('####### Comment '||i||' '||apex_application.g_f01(i));
  end loop;
END;
```

5. Finally your `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO vehicles(brand, model, comment)
VALUES(:P27_BRAND, :P27_MODEL, apex_application.g_f01(i));
```

6. When you check that everything works fine, change the process code:

```
BEGIN
    for i in apex_application.g_f01.FIRST..apex_application.g_f01.LAST loop
        INSERT INTO vehicles(brand, model, comment)
        VALUES(:P27_BRAND, :P27_MODEL, apex_application.g_f01(i));
    end loop;
END;
```

**EDIT**

7. Select the column where the inputs are, on the right find the **Security** section and disable **Escape special characters**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try to implement it on my application to test it

Comment: Please upvote :D Ask if something didnt work

Comment: I've tried to test it on my app but came with some problems, my report is showing me this on every cell : <input type="text" name="f01" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="" placeholder="Comment 1" />. And secondly, where am I supposed to paste the INSERT code ?  Thank you in advance,

Comment: I added the 6th step (Where to add the insert....). Yes it adds an input DOM element for every row, now you should style those inputs with some basic CSS.

Comment: Hello David, sorry for updating this post a week later, I've been quite busy on other tasks.  What I was trying to say in my previous comment, is that my interactive report is litterally showing this in every row : <input type="text" name="f01" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="" placeholder="Comment 1" />. I guess it's supposed to just show a blank cell with the possiblity to write in it, because actuallty i can't. You can take a look at the screenshot on the update of my question

Comment: Check the EDIT.

Comment: Thank you very much David for your answer and for taking the time to help me. It's working fine now ! :-)