# How to refresh a PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region without a page submit

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex v21.1, I'm working on a dynamic insert form which displays a certain numbers of textfields based on a numbers selected by the user in a LOV.

It's currently working using the solution based on one of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726189/browse-the-values-of-multiple-fields-and-insert-them-into-the-same-column) (thanks davidm)

I am using an Interactive Report with a SQL Query that SELECT n APEX_ITEM.TEXT components.

I would like to improve this solution and use a PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region using HTP.P, because this would allow me to create textfields with  and more css classes, which would give my apex_item components a more native look of the declarative apex items.

Unfortunately, it's not possible as far as I know to partially refresh a PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region.

Is there a way that could look like a refresh for the user, using a Set Value DA or an existing plug-in, that would allow the submit of the value in the LOV, and so dynamically generate my textfields ?

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: In order to refresh a region, it needs to support partial page refresh. A pl/sql dynamic region doesn't do that so you can't refresh it (not with DA, not with plugin). A workaround is to use a classic report and select your static content from dual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***

If this can help anyone, I've found [this plug-in](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:6452745336830::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.FOS.PLSQL_DYNAMIC_CONTENT) which gives you the possibility to refresh a PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region.